# How to get json strings in a structure from json docs using by Unmarshal in golang

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

The sample code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type ClassRoom struct {
    Student struct {
        Name string
        /*
           Address struct {
               City string
               Zip  int
           } `json:"address"`
        */
        Address []string `json:"address"` //here, Want to get json string
        Age     int      `json:"age"`
    } `json:"student"`
    ClassCode int `json:"code"`
}

func main() {
    jsonDocs := `[
    {"student":{"name":"jss","address":{"City":"Seoul","Zip":54},"Age":28},"ClassCode":1234}]`

    var node []ClassRoom

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonDocs), &node)
    fmt.Println(node)
}
```

I want Address variable of json string type (like `{"City":"Seoul"....}`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) instead of `[]string`, example:

```
type ClassRoom struct {
    Student struct {
        Name string
        Address json.RawMessage `json:"address"` //here, Want to get json string
        Age     int             `json:"age"`
    } `json:"student"`
    ClassCode int `json:"code"`
}

func main() {
    jsonDocs := `[{"student":{"name":"jss","address":{"City":"Seoul","Zip":54},"Age":28},"ClassCode":1234}]`
    var node []ClassRoom

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonDocs), &node)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", node[0].Student.Address)

    var addr struct {
        City string
        Zip  int
    }
    json.Unmarshal(node[0].Student.Address, &addr)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", addr)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/dppU5Y-7Bw)

Comment: @J.soo if my answer helped, you can select it by clicking the checkmark :)